# How to do an nginx redirect excluding an IP address and a path?

Tags: nginx

I need to redirect to a URL unless the user is coming from within our internal IP address **or** if they are accessing a particular path.

I've tried this:

```
location ~* /foobar {
    break;
}

location ~* / {
    if ($remote_addr != 111.222.333.444) {
        rewrite ^ https://external.tld/
    }
}
```

But that doesn't seem to work. That particular configuration causes a 404 when going to https://mydomain.tld/foobar and a "Welcome to nginx!" page when accessing it from within our IP address.  However, accessing https://mydomain.tld/foobar outside of our IP address does properly redirect to https://external.tld/

Comment: Questions seeking installation, configuration or diagnostic help must include the desired end state, the specific problem or error, sufficient information about the configuration and environment to reproduce it, and attempted solutions. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers and are unlikely to get good answers.

Comment: @djdomi What do you recommend for making the problem statement clearer?

Comment: show us nginx -T and explain what is does not work means, currently you just tell us the half way ;)

Comment: @djdomi Thanks.  I added more clarification to what is happening with the given configuration. Unfortunately, I'm not allowed to post the results of `nginx -T`.

Comment: if it's only a single url, is a subdomain also possible?

Comment: No, just that one URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't want (or are not allowed) to show your full server block, I'll make some guesses. What most likely happened with your configuration? You created two additional location blocks which are used to process **any** incoming request. Check the `location` directive [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location). The only two location types that can overtake a request from regex matching location are exact location (`location = /uri { ... }`) and do-not-check-regex prefix location (`location ^~ /prefix { ... }`). Otherwise, the first regex matching location will be chosen.

Every server block has its root directory, even if it isn't specified explicitly using the `root` directive. It is chosen using **prefix** (specified at the [compilation time](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/installoptions/), can be checked with the `nginx -V` command) and `/html` suffix. Lets assume your nginx prefix is `/usr/share/nginx`. Then your default root will be at the `/usr/share/nginx/html` directory, unless explicitly specified using the `root /some/path` directive.

Default nginx behavior when serving a request can be described as `try_files $uri $uri/ =404`.

Lets assume we have a `https://mydomain.tld/foobar` request. To serve it your first `location ~* /foobar { break; }` will be chosen as the first matched regex location. The first directive `break` means that processing the current set of [`ngx_http_rewrite_module`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html) directives will be stopped. But there are none of those directives (except the `break` one) inside this location block! Yes, that means that this `break` directive is useless here. Next, nginx will check for the existence of a `/usr/share/nginx/html/foobar` file, an index file from the `/usr/share/nginx/html/foobar/` directory (default is `index.html`), and after both checks fails, return an `HTTP 404 Not Found` error.

Now lets assume we have a `https://mydomain.tld/` request. Your first location block won't match it, so the second one `location ~* / { ... }` is chosen to process this request (this location block will match any possible valid request). If an IP address check won't pass, a redirection will take its place. But if it would pass, nginx will process your request the same way as described above, returning your default welcome `index.html` file from the `/usr/share/nginx/html/` directory.

Looks like you don't understand how directives from the [`ngx_http_rewrite_module`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html) are processed. Read again the very first part of the documentation:

> The `break`, `if`, `return`, `rewrite`, and `set` directives are processed in the following order:
>
> - the directives of this module specified on the server level are executed sequentially;
> - repeatedly:
>
>   - a location is searched based on a request URI;
>   - the directives of this module specified inside the found location are executed sequentially;
>   - the loop is repeated if a request URI was rewritten, but not more than 10 times.

You can place your checks at the server block level:

```
if ($uri = /foobar) {
    break;
}
if ($remote_addr != 111.222.333.444) {
    rewrite ^ https://external.tld/
}
```

The above `break` directive will work as expected, an execution of `ngx_http_rewrite_module` directives on the server level will be stopped. That means that any other directive from that module (like `set`, `if`, `return`, `rewrite` etc.), if any, should be placed **before** the above block. That does not apply to the `ngx_http_rewrite_module` directives placed at the location level.

There is one more possible caveat. If your `https://mydomain.tld/foobar` page makes use of any assets (scripts, styles, images etc.), access to those assets should be allowed too. For example, you can change the condition to allow anything started with `/foobar` prefix using `if ($uri ~* ^/foobar) { break; }` block. If their addresses cannot be checked with a single regex, you can use several `if (...) { break; }` blocks.